# Change text with math random

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a Magic 8 Ball on codepen, but unfortunately I cannot get any text to appear. Currently I am using Math Random to get all of the different answers I need, but I'm pretty fuzzy as to how the html and JavaScript interact. Here's what I have so far:

HTML:

```js
//JavaScript:

var words = [
  'It is certain',
  'It is decidedly so',
  'Etc',
];

var getRandomWord = function () {
  return words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
 };
  
$(function() {
  $('.eball').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.textbox').html(getRandomWord());
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="eball">
    <div class="triangle"></div>
    <div class="textbox"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/qLk4nqdb/1/ Did you import jquery?

Comment: `eball` has no height, so the `mouseenter` event never fires.

Comment: As torazaburo mentioned, your code is fine, except that height is the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine with a minor change. Give your `.eball` class a fixed height.

The problem is that your `.eball` div starts with zero content, which causes the `div` to collapse completely. You will be unable to fire the `mouseenter` event since there is no "area" to enter. Giving the `div` you want to trigger `mouseenter` on a fixed size (specifically a height) will solve this issue. Another solution would be to start the div with some initial text or a `&nbsp;` so it's not empty.

```js
var words = [
  'It is certain',
  'It is decidedly so',
  'Etc',
];

var getRandomWord = function () {
  return words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
};

$(function() {
  $('.eball').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.textbox').html(getRandomWord());
  });
});
```

```css
.eball {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: grey;
  height: 50px;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="eball">
  <p class="textbox"></p>
</div>
```